# How to use single colon when using variable for slicing?

Tags: python, slice

I want to use a variable for storing a slicing expression.
This is what I try:

```
    if variable is not None:
        var = variable
    elif self.__filter is not None:
        var = self.__filter
    else:
        # this doesn't work, : alone understandably gives a syntax error
        var = ':'
```

var is then used here:

```
return stuff[var]
```

I want to do this to get a better structure in my code. The alternative would be to return this expressions depending on case:

```
return stuff[variable]
return stuff[self.__filter]
return stuff[:]
```

Exception raised: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Is there a way to assign the colon to var so it can be used in the slicing expression (escaping or similar stuff) or do I have to use `var = slice(0, self.getNumberOfVariables())` instead?

P.S.: I did search before asking, but didn't find anything like this. Sorry if I missed a duplicate.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: And what are you trying to "slice"?  a string?   what[:100] ? You can't pit a , in the middle of a slicing process. `slice` == `self.__dset[...]` that's a slice, and it takes two parameters,  `self.__dset[0:X]` you can't do `self:__dset[0:X, var]`, there's no parameters there :)

Comment: I'm slicing a big dataset and I'm currently writing an answer to this question myself. I thought about not posting the question, but it could be valuable for others. Error given `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Comment: Okay. Should have said that. This is numpy stuff. [slice1, slice2] is short for [slice1][slice2]. The comma is not the problem.

Comment: That's correct, if this is Numpy you're fine because it contains a __index__ method when passing a tupled object to the slice :) Ignore my questions and statements prior to this one :P

Comment: @Torxed: Removed numpy stuff, to make the example simpler. Feel free to give a better answer.

Comment: AH! Now i see what you're trying to do! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old post but it just popped up as a top result on Google, so thought I'd answer it to help any others.

The colon `:` in a slice is just a separator between `[start:stop:step]`.  What is often not explicitly written is `None` when one of `start`, `stop` or `step` are left to their default values.

This is easier to see in examples:

```
# Slice with all parameters specified
# start:1, stop:4, step:1    
seq[1:4:1]

# Slice with default step value (default=1)
# start:1, stop:4, step:1
# All the following are equivalent    
seq[1:4:None]
seq[1:4:]
seq[1:4]

# Slice with default stop value (default = len(seq))
# start:1, stop:len(seq), step:1
# All the following are equivalent    
seq[1:None:1]
seq[1::1]

# Slice with default step and stop value
# start:1, stop:len(seq), step:1
# All the following are equivalent    
seq[1:None:None]
seq[1::]
seq[1:]

# Slice with default start value
# start:1, stop:4, step:1
# All the following are equivalent    
seq[None:4:1]
seq[:4:1]

# Slice with all default values
# start:1, stop:len(seq), step:1
# All the following are equivalent    
seq[None:None:None]
seq[::]
seq[:]
```

So to answer your question, to use the `:` in a slice variable doesn't make sense, since you're asking to use a separator.  Though it is confusing since you don't have to explicitly state `None` when creating a slice directly, so this makes the `:` look like an operator.

TLDR; when using the `slice` type, you must explicitly state `None`.
So `seq[slice(None, None, None)]` is equivalent to `seq[::]`.

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible to use the colon directly. It is a literal notation for an operation; Python does not generally allow this sort of punctuation to be used directly, instead requiring use of a function (cf. arithmetic operators and the corresponding functions in the `operator` module).

The function to use is the builtin function `slice`, which return an explicit representation of a slice. Use `slice(None)` to include everything.

An example:

```
>>> s = slice(None)
>>> x = range(10)
>>> x[s]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: slice(None) is for sure better, than using slice(0, len()). That's why I upvoted this. But I don't feel like I can accept this as answer, because it doesn't say how to use the colon (not possible) or why this isn't possible.

Answer (score -1):

The expression `stuff[var]` immutably fixes the possibilities to something, that can be expressed using a single variable.
You have to think about how stuff gets interpreted.
First the code gets parsed. At this time gets fixed which syntax is used.
`start:stop:step` is an expression, the compiler accepts as a slice. A special case of this is `:`. Other possibilities are scalars, lists and slice objects. Single objects.

Using var in the getter, I can only set var to a list, a scalar or a slice object.
When trying to assign colon syntax stuff to var, I just get a string literal and string literals don't get parsed by the getter/setter methods.
you simply can't change the syntax by assigning some value to a variable.